# consecutive increasing subsequences in permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to count the groups (bad description) of consecutive increasing elements in a permutation of $n$, i.e. for $n=5$ we could have 34125, so we have 3 groups ${\{3,4}\},\; {\{1,2}\},\; {\{5}\}$ of lengths 2, 2, and 1 respectively.

I'm trying to find the average length of the $m$th group and the average length of any group.

I'm looking at the first problem like this:
If the $m$th group begins in position $m+k$, we have the first $m-1$ groups occupying the the first $m+k-1$ positions, and this  can be chosen in 
$${m+k-2 \choose m-1}{n \choose m-k-1}$$ 
ways. If the $m$th group has 1 element there are ${n-m-k+1 \choose 1}(n-m-k)!$ possibilities. If the $m$th group has 2 elements we have ${n-m-k+1 \choose 2}(n-m-k-1)!$, so we end up with 
$${m+k-2 \choose m-1}{n \choose m-k-1}\left[{n-m-k+1 \choose 1}(n-m-k)!+\ldots \right ]$$
Obviously accounting for all possible positions of the $m$th group makes this an ugly expression.

Any suggestions on this question or the other would be appreciated.